# How to delete a file in a specific folder in Python?

Tags: python, file, directory

I know you can use `os.remove(myfile)` to delete files. But what is the default folder location of this file? How do I change the folder directory?

Comment: don't you know where your have file on disk ?  We don't know too. If you know folder then you can create full path `fullpath = os.path.join(folder, filename)` and then use `os.remove(fullpath)`.

Comment: To understand how to access a specific folder, you need to understand [the difference between absolute and relative paths](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1444892)

Answer (score 1):

The default folder is your current working directory, likely to be where you started your python interpreter. You can check it by `print(os.getcwd())` to display it.

To change the current working directory, you can run `os.chdir('C:/MyFolder')`, where you can swap `C:/MyFolder` to any desired path you want.